# With apache server, Home page working properly but other links and pages gives 404 not found error

Tags: ubuntu, deployment, server, apache2, web-deployment

I am an new with apache server deployment & recently I have deployed one python website using apache with SSL Certificate on Ubuntu server.

I have not used .htaccess file and done all the configuration in virtualhost directive of sites-available directory.

Virtualhost code is as below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/panel/
        ServerName panel.myweb.com
        ServerAdmin mayank.prajapati@myweb.com
        ServerAlias www.panel.myweb.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/html/panel/>
        #       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +Includes
                AllowOverride FileInfo Options
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noe
# Sub domain a.localhost
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/panel/
        ServerName panel.myweb.com
        ServerAdmin mayank.prajapati@myweb.com
        ServerAlias www.panel.myweb.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/html/panel/>
        #       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +Includes
                AllowOverride FileInfo Options
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all

        </Directory>

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/cloudflare/myweb.com.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/cloudflare/myweb.com.key

</VirtualHost>
```

So now `https://panel.myweb.com`(home page) URL working properly and give me expected webpage. Also when I click on sidebar menu it also working properly and give me webpage e.g `https://panel.myweb.com/mytestpage`  BUT

When I copy & paste other pages links e.g `https://panel.myweb.com/mytestpage` in new tab it gives me error `Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.`. Even I refresh other pages links also I am getting the same error.

I have been trying to find the solution since 2 days and tried many other different options but not working as expected.

Thanks.

Comment: Why there been close request on my question. Anything wrong with my question ? It is valid question and clearly I have provided all information here.